# batch iterate string with whitespace delimiter, find word containing substring

Tags: windows, batch-file

I don't understand why this doesn't work

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set contents=sdflkm efsdf sdfkns CRQ239478239
for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%i in ("%contents%") do (
  set str=%%i
  echo str: !str:~0,3!
    if "!str:~0,3!"=="CRQ" (
      set revision=!str!
    )
)
echo revision: %revision%
```

I want to extract the word in the string that begins with "CRQ". But this for loop only does one iteration, grabbing the first 3 letters of the string.  The output is just `str: sdf`.  It should check the first 3 letters of every word in the string, and if the first 3 letters are 'CRQ', it should set the revision variable to the word containing CRQ.  How do I do this?

Comment: You're choosing the first token `%%i` of the string, `sdflkm efsdf sdfkns CRQ239478239`, the result will therefore be `str`=`sdflkm` and subsequently `revision`=`sdf`, that's why it's not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` command will iterate through *lines* of input. Since your string only consists of a single line you only get 1 iteration through your loop.

The `for` loop is tokenizing that single line into multiple tokens. It is passing the first token to `%i`, then, thanks to the asterisk in `tokens=1*`, it puts the rest in `%j`. If you change your script a little, you can see this:

```
set contents=sdflkm efsdf sdfkns CRQ239478239
for /f "tokens=1*" %%i in ("%contents%") do (
  set str=%%i
  echo str: !str:~0,3!
  echo rest: %%j
    if "!str:~0,3!"=="CRQ" (
      set revision=!str!
    )
)
echo revision: %revision%
```

which outputs:

```
str: sdf
rest: efsdf sdfkns CRQ239478239
revisionx:
```

My solution is to create a subroutine that you can call recursively on the remaining tokens until you hit the one you want:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set contents=sdflkm efsdf sdfkns CRQ239478239
call :ParseTokens %contents%
echo revision: %revision%

rem Subroutine ParseTokens
:ParseTokens
set ToParse=%*
for /f "tokens=1*" %%i in ("%ToParse%") do (
    set str=%%i
    if "!str:~0,3!"=="CRQ" (
      set revision=!str!
      exit /b
    ) else (
        call :ParseTokens %%j
    )
)
exit /b
```

Comment: You should seperate the sub from program flow with a `goto :eof` Shifting arguments is IMO much simpler and doesn't require delayed expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your `For /F` loop to a standard `For` loop:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Contents=sdflkm efsdf sdfkns CRQ239478239"
Set "Revision="
For %%A In (%Contents%) Do (Set "Str=%%A"
    Echo Str: !Str:~,3!
    If /I "!Str:~,3!"=="CRQ" Set "Revision=!Str!")
Set "Str="
If Defined Revision Echo %Revision%
Pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your for to a simple one and use `%contents%` without quotes.

```
for %%i in (%contents%) do (
```

Just another variant with a call and shifting arguments:

```
@echo off & SETLOCAL
set contents=sdflkm efsdf sdfkns CRQ239478239
Call :Sub %contents%
echo revision: %revision%
goto :eof
:sub
set str=%1
echo str: %str:~0,3%
if "%str:~0,3%"=="CRQ" set revision=%str%
If "%~2" neq "" (shift & goto :sub)
```

Comment: …just pipped you :-)

Comment: @Compo but only by seconds ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another method to achieve this, using a file as input called `My CRQs.txt`
The idea here is to break up each string into words so `findstr` will only return what you asked off it.:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("My CRQs.txt") do (
   for %%a in (%%i) do echo %%a | findstr /IBRC:"CRQ"
)
```